# Google Map API Key not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I follow Google's directions:

Log in, go to the API Console, activate the JSv3 (and 2) map API, go to the access section, request a new key, use their 'hello world' code, using my key instead of the one in the sample and it works, for a whole 3 seconds. Then I get an alert with the following message:

*Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v2 on this site.*

Code is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
    GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function() {
      alert("You clicked the map.");
     });
  }
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Dang, I solved it, was calling v2 not v3...

Comment: Great - Take a look at: [Is it okay to answer my own question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16930/185112).

Answer (score 0):

Per Sean's advice above - I was calling v2 of the api, not v3, v2 is being/already deprecated so that was probably the problem.

Comment: Just for the record, version 2 still works (though people should use version 3). The problem is trying to use a v3 key with v2 or vice-versa

Comment: For the record, a v3 (short) key will work in a v2 map provided Version 2 has been enabled for that key and the referrer domain is set up correctly in the API Console. Version 2 (long) keys continue to work for v2 maps in the same way as they always have, but can't be used in v3 maps.